# AttributeError: module 'dateutil.parser' has no attribute 'parse' pandas on python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7

I tried install pandas via command `pip install pandas` and got error:

```
import pandas
../python3.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 440, in <module>
parse_date = _date_parser.parse
AttributeError: module 'dateutil.parser' has no attribute 'parse'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip install python-dateutil==2.5.* 
and then install pandas. It solves that problem.

Comment: thanks, python-dateutil has made release on Feb 5, 2019 maybe pandas didn't take it into account